# Can you reassign keys on Mac for Logitech K310 washable keyboard?

Tags: mac, logitech-keyboard

I know it's not being sold as compatible for Mac but as intensive typer I like the idea of having an always clean keyboard.

I already read [this review](http://mamageek.co.uk/2013/07/01/review-logitech-k310-washable-keyboard/)  so I wonder if someone managed to make it fully functional on Mac reassigning keys to make them useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I went out for my third Apple extended keyboard after another spilled drink on my living room setup (iMac, family of 4), the Logitech board was a logical choice. Those Apple boards don't come cheap and for half the money I bought the K310.
After years of use, here's what to like and what not:

1 - Modifier keys are easily remapped on a Mac, I disables Caps Lock (I hate Caps LOCK!1!), switched command and option [see this (Dutch) screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y46Un.jpg) - Apple remaps windows key as command key when hooked up to a windows keyboard. I switched them back, the command modifier feels better right next to the space bar. I also popped out the windows key and the Alt key and switched them physically. This way it makes more sense, the Windows key being the command key and the Alt key being, well, the Alt key.
On the other side of the space bar there's the Alt Gr(?) key which functions as command key in my setup.

2 - As for the function keys: There is a big FN modifier key which lets you use some of the Multimedia functionality: volume/mute and start up iTunes, play/pauze previous next song. And the weirdest combo: command-option F14/F15 (Scroll lock/Pauze Break) controls the screen brightness.

3 - The keyboard itself is reasonable to type on; the board is not as stiff as I would like it, island style keys have good travel. The plecemnet of the keys is fine, I would like the left shift key a little wider, but the right shift key makes up for that. I'm not a touch typist, so I like the white keys with black marking, works well in the semi-dark. The markings do not fade or wear off.

4 - Washability is really a lifesaver, the keyboard is unsusceptible to spilled drinks, crumbs, cigarette ashes (yeah, I know). There is a small brush attached to the bottom of the board, you can get rid of the worst crumbs between the keys with that. If the keys get too sticky, throw it in lukewarm water with a bit of detergent, give it a good rub with a dishwasher brush, rinse it and let it dry for a while. You could use it instantly but the water keeps leaking out of the board for a while, so shake it off or use a blow dryer (not recommended)

After a few wash-ups over the years, the keys felt not as good to the touch, lost their subtleness in travel. I took a photo for key placement reference, popped them all out, applied a little silicone spray to the keyholes and the reverse side of each key, put them all back and the board felt as new.

All things considered, the Logitech K310 is a solid Mac compatible board without any issues or surprises than can stand the test of time and users for a fair price.